# Retrieve list of all interconnected stored procedures in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have list of stored procedures to deploy in Oracle to a staging server. I end up missing a few procedures while deploying.

Is there a way of getting a list of all stored procedures which are getting called within the scope of another?

Comment: I removed the reference to a "tool" as shopping questions are explicitly off-topic on all of Stack Exchange, see the [faq].

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ALL_DEPENDENCIES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1068.htm#i1576452) view to obtain this.

ALL_DEPENDENCIES describes the dependencies between packages, triggers, procedures and functions accessible to the current user. USER_DEPENDENCIES does the same for those objects owned by the current user and DBA_DEPENDENCIES, if you have access, for everything in the database.

The following would give you a list of packages, procedures and functions for the current user that rely on another package, procedure of function that that user has access to.

```
select *
  from all_dependencies
 where type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
   and owner = user
   and type in ('PROCEDURE','FUNCTION','PACKAGE','PACKAGE BODY')
   and referenced_type in ('PROCEDURE','FUNCTION','PACKAGE','PACKAGE BODY')
```

You can play around a bit if you want, for instance I would probably exclude SYS objects etc.